# How do I add a custom property to a Role Claim in .Net Core?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I am using Cookie Authentication instead of Identity Core.
I am looping through what roles a user should have from a custom table and adding Role Claims like this:

```
if (aartsUser != null)
{
    #region Create Claims
    // UserName claim and StaffId claim.  Will need StaffId to write to tables such as UploadStaffId for FacUpload.
    var claims = new List<Claim>
    {
        new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, loginModel.UserName),
        new Claim("StaffId", aartsUser.StaffID.ToString())
    };
    // Role Claims
    foreach(Position p in aartsUser.Positions)
    {
        claims.Add(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, p.Role.RoleCd));
    }
    #endregion

    var claimsIdentity = new ClaimsIdentity(claims, CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
    await HttpContext.SignInAsync(new ClaimsPrincipal(claimsIdentity));

    return Redirect(loginModel?.ReturnUrl ?? "/");
}
```

RoleCd in this line:

```
claims.Add(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, p.Role.RoleCd));
```

comes from a Role Entity I have:

```
[Table("role")]
public class Role
{
    [Key]
    [Column("role_id")]
    public short RoleID { get; set; }
    [Column("role_nm")]
    public string RoleName { get; set; }
    [Column("role_cd")]
    public string RoleCd { get; set; }
    [Column("role_group_nm")]
    public string RoleGroupName { get; set; }
    [Column("role_class_cd")]
    public string RoleClassCd { get; set; }

    public List<Position> Positions { get; set; }
}
```

My question is how do I add a custom property to the role claim.
I have an account info page where a user can see their roles.
But I show the RoleCd from our custom table.
I still want to use this code as the Role but I was asked to also display the RoleNm which is like a text description.

How do I add a custom property like Description in this line?

```
claims.Add(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, p.Role.RoleCd));
```

Something like:

```
claims.Add(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, p.Role.RoleCd).Properties.Add("Description", p.Role.RoleName));
```

But it says cannot convert from void to System.Security.Claims.Claim.

Comment: FWIW I would look it up on the page that needs it. Names can change, what you have stored in the cookie will be stale.

Answer (score 3):

I figured it out.

Here is what I did:

```
            var claims = new List<Claim>
            {
                new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, loginModel.UserName),
                new Claim("StaffId", aartsUser.StaffID.ToString())
            };
            // Role Claims
            foreach(Position p in aartsUser.Positions)
            {
                claims.Add(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, p.Role.RoleCd));
                Claim newClaim = claims.Where(c => c.Value == p.Role.RoleCd).FirstOrDefault();
                newClaim.Properties.Add("Description", p.Role.RoleName);
            }
```

Comment: kindly mention the reason why it has been voted down. If there is some serious issue with the approach, please elaborate it so that others could avoid it! Thanks

Comment: I also tried such straightforward aproach. But when I check granted permission, the added property is lost: there is only one property in `Properties` - with key `http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claimproperties/ShortTypeName` and value `role`...

Answer (score 0):

I have better solution based on your own answer. So you don't need to query the claims again.

```
       foreach(Position p in aartsUser.Positions)
        {
            Claim newClaim = new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, p.Role.RoleCd));
            newClaim.Properties.Add("Description", p.Role.RoleName);
            claims.Add(newClaim);
        }
```